# How can I disable vibration during sleep focus?

Tags: iphone, vibrate, focus

When I am sleeping I do not want to feel the iPhone vibrating in my hand. That is the most jarring thing that will keep me from getting back to sleep ever.

Can I somehow disable vibration when my phone enters sleep focus?

Comment: Sorry if this sounds like a silly question, but why is your iPhone in your hand when you sleep?

Comment: I pick it up to check the time when I wake up mid sleep and answer urgent messages then hope to go back to sleep absent any overly intense stimulus in the interim.

Comment: I've looked at all the options in the Sleep focus and there doesn't seem to be a way to turn off vibration. I guess you need to go to Sounds & Haptics and turn off Vibrate on Silent.

Comment: Unless there is a way to modify that setting in automator either by a time schedule or triggered upon entering sleep focus?

Comment: When you set sleep focus it will only allow notifications (and by that vibration) from apps and people you allowed to get through. Simply remove all apps and people from the allow list and you will have no vibrations.